# Predicate Logic Expression: "Nobody loves anybody."

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Express the following in predicate logic: "Nobody loves anybody."

$$P(x): \text{x is a person.}$$
$$L(x,y): \text{x loves y.}$$

My attempt was:

$$\neg[\exists x(P(x) \land \forall y P(y) \longrightarrow L(x,y))]$$

Although my instructor wrote it as:

$$\neg[\exists x(P(x) \land ( \forall y P(y) \longrightarrow L(x,y)))]$$

I do not get why he nested the implies in separate parentheses.

More so I am not able to semantically tell the difference between the two formulae.

Anyone?

Comment: It's about operator precedence.  $p\wedge q \to r$ is *usually* interpreted as $(p\wedge q)\to r$ rather than $p\wedge (q\to r)$ *though not always*.  Personally I'd have wrapped the quantifier scope;  $$\neg\exists x~\Big(P(x)\wedge \forall y~\big(P(y)\to L(x,y)\big)\Big)$$ which is "nobody loves everybody," by the way.

Comment: Nobody loves anybody does not have the same meaning as nobody loves any body.

Comment: @Sharma: Sorry, miscounted.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I did too. The (pointless) outer brackets don't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually both of the formulas you have are wrong in some way. In both, the $\forall y$ only binds the $y$ in $P(y)$, leaving the $y$ in $L(x,y)$ free. In your professor's sentence, the parenthesis before $\forall y$ should come right after it. Finally, there's no need for the outer brackets. Thus:
$$
\neg\exists x~\Big(P(x) \land \forall y \big(P(y) \to L(x,y)\big)\Big)
$$
However, this isn't right: it's equivalent to
$$\begin{align}
\forall x~\Big(P(x) \to \neg\forall y~\big(P(y) \to L(x,y)\big)\Big) &\iff \forall x~\Big(P(x) \to \exists y~\big(P(y) \land \neg L(x,y)\big)\Big)
\end{align}$$
which means "everybody doesn't love someone", or equivalently, nobody loves *everybody*. *Everybody* does not mean *anybody*. I am assuming that "nobody loves anybody" does **not** mean the same thing as "nobody loves *just* anybody" (i.e. everybody).

I take "nobody loves anybody" to mean for all people $x$ and $y$, $x$ does not love $y$:
$$
\forall x~\forall y~\Big(\big(P(x)\land P(y)\big)\to \neg L(x,y)\Big)
$$

Comment: Your interpretation is the same to say that love doesn't exist between people? Sad :(

Comment: @Masacroso Basically yes. The question isn't whether that's *true* ;)

Comment: I think your interpretation is not good after all (Im not english speaker anyway) because I feel is different to say "nodoby loves someone". It is hard to see these things for not a english speaker. I love you a bit anyway, so it cant be true :)

Comment: I am a fluent native English speaker. One would never say "Nobody loves someone."

Comment: @GrahamKemp OK I'll go for that, thanks.

Comment: I actually asked him "You mean anybody or everybody?" and he kept on ranting at me for "not recognizing that they mean the same thing."
I see anybody as being a specific person. In other words I see anybody as a random element from the everybody set. And he told me this was incorrect.

Thanks to everyone, comments here and there helped.
BrianO you're a king! My instructor was not being clear at all, especially for the need of $y$ to be bound, otherwise it would lose its meaning.

Comment: Also I recognize the differences.
But I'll falsely take anybody=everybody just for the goddamn midterms. Heh.

Comment: Haha -- best to avoid the rants and assume that *in this guy's class*, "everbody" and "anybody" mean the same thing ;) There are subtleties, contexts where that isn't so, but... what the hey.